# No return value after second+ iteration

Tags: javascript, oop

I don't know whats wrong with this:

```
      var get_depth = function(item, depth) {
        if(item.parent_id !== null) {
          get_depth(get_item_by_id(item.parent_id),depth+1);
        } else {
          alert ("return: " + depth);
          return depth;
        }
      };
```

The alert message always throws a correct depth but the variable where i want to have the value stored in only accept one iteration (return value = 1) after two or more iterations the value of my variable is undefined. I do not understand that.

Comment: how are you calling it the first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you should return the value each time :

```
 var get_depth = function(item, depth) {
        if(item.parent_id !== null) {
          return get_depth(get_item_by_id(item.parent_id),depth+1);
        } else {
          alert ("return: " + depth);
          return depth;
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 2):

you're missing return.

```
 var get_depth = function(item, depth) {
        if(item.parent_id !== null) {
          return get_depth(get_item_by_id(item.parent_id),depth+1);
        } else {
          alert ("return: " + depth);
          return depth;
        }
      };
```

And why aren't you using this syntax? I find it easier to go through:

```
function get_depth(item, depth) {
  if(item.parent_id !== null) {
    return get_depth(get_item_by_id(item.parent_id),depth+1);
  } else {
    alert ("return: " + depth);
    return depth;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you man! It works, although i do not really understand this statement.

Comment: Hm... i do not see any difference. i put this in a var get_depth to keep my source-code clean. it is a method call as part of an object.

Comment: I see, it's probably just a matter of habit. Method can be a part of object even it's not declared as a variable. But as I said, both are good.